# cypress my coverage is Unknowned but my test are working

Tags: reactjs, cypress, code-coverage

I am using Cypress to do my unittests and all my tests work however my coverage rate is unknown. My project only uses ReactJs

Looking on the internet the answers said that it is necessary that the cypress and front folders are in the same location.
Here is the architecture of my project and it does not work and i dont understand why.

[image]

I have tried to reinstall cypress and reinstall coverage
if someone has the solution.
Thank you for your answers